# How to create a shared queue in Go?

Tags: go, concurrency, parallel-processing, priority-queue, goroutine

I am trying to implement the least connections algorithm for a load balancer. I am using priority queue to keep the count of connections per server in a sorted order.
Here is the code:

```
server = spq[0]
serverNumber = server.value

updatedPriority = server.priority + 1 // Increment connection count for server

spq.update(server, serverNumber, updatedPriority)

targetUrl, err := url.Parse(configuration.Servers[serverNumber])
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

// Send the request to the selected server
httputil.NewSingleHostReverseProxy(targetUrl).ServeHTTP(w, r)

updatedPriority = server.priority - 1 // Decrement connection count for server
spq.update(server, serverNumber, updatedPriority)
```

where `spq` is my priority queue.

This code will run for every request the balancer will receive.
But I am not getting correct results after logging the state of queue for every request.
For example in one case I saw the queue contained the same server twice with different priorities.

I am sure this has something to do with synchronising and locking the queue across the requests. But I am not sure what is the correct approach in this particular case.

Comment: This seems like an odd use case for a queue - queues are for lists of items where you push to one end and pop from one end. You're using this to "keep the count of connections per server", which seems like the job of a map, or possibly just a server struct with a field for connection count.

Comment: This is racy for sure. Nothing here prevents two concurrent requests from simultaneously selecting spq[0], while a third calls update, and then the updates to the priority field are racing *again*. Compile with -race and it'll crash before long. You have to do all this atomically: select a server, update it's priority, reorder the queue.

Comment: You haven't said how many servers you're dealing with, but if the number is small, just use a map (or slice) and a mutex. You really only need the priority queue thing if iteration gets prohibitively expensive, which seems very unlikely to me.

Comment: @Adrian It's a priority queue which would give keep the list sorted and I can get the server with least connections easily. I thought this would be a use case for a priority queue.

Comment: @Peter It's just a pet project. But ideally I would want it to be able to handle a large number of servers. If we make it atomic, wouldn't it affect the performance since I will have to wait for the response from the server before updating the queue. Then maybe this is not the best approach for least connection algorithm in a load balancer.

Comment: A queue is not just a sorted list. [A queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue) is a collection where "the principal (or only) operations on the collection are the addition of entities to the rear terminal position, known as enqueue, and removal of entities from the front terminal position, known as dequeue." Your use case calls for a simple sorted list, not a priority queue.

Comment: @Adrian I don't mean to argue but "in a [priority queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue), an element with high priority is served before an element with low priority." What I understood from this is that I will always get the value with the highest priority whenever the priority queue is updated.

Comment: You don't need to hold the lock for the duration of the request. Grab the lock, do the selection and re-prioritization, release the lock, handle the request, lock, re-prioritize again, unlock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is really your code that runs in multiple goroutines, then you clearly have race.

I do not understand spq.update. At first it looks like it is a function that reorders the queue to have the server with minimum number of calls at element 0, but then why does it need both server and serverNumber? serverNumber appears to be a unique ID for the server, and since you already have the server, why do you need that?

In any case, you should have a sync.Mutex shared by all goroutines, and lock the mutex before the first line, and unlock after spq.update, also  you should again lock it after proxy call, and unlock when all done. The line that subtracts 1 from server.priority will only work if server is a pointer. If it is not a pointer, you're losing all the updates to server happened during the call.

Comment: I am using this https://golang.org/pkg/container/heap/#example__priorityQueue implementation of priority queue. I guess you are right the method doesn't need both ID and the server. I will try using the sync.Mutex like you said and update it here.

Comment: So server is a pointer. If you add the mutex as I described, it should eliminate the race here. Anywhere you access the queue, you have to use the same mutex to lock to prevent any races.

Comment: You might want to look into using this heap queue: https://github.com/jwells131313/goethe#heap